# Unable to start activity java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null while getting list of contact. Not able to locate the error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime-error

I was following a tutorial on Android development and it had SQL in it. The program was to add and retrieve all the contacts created. When I run it, the below error showed up.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.contactmanager, PID: 7147
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.contactmanager/com.test.contactmanager.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:570)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at com.test.contactmanager.data.DatabaseHandler.getAllContacts(DatabaseHandler.java:132)
        at com.test.contactmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Can someone tell me what does this error means? and what should change? I tried debugging but to no avail. After reading I got to know it is happening because NULL is passed somewhere but while adding the first contact, id should be NULL. If not, please tell me what should I change?

This is my Contact Class

```java
public class Contact {
    //Contains Contact Information of a person
    String name;
    int id;
    String phoneNumber;

    public Contact(String name, int id, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Contact() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

This is the function where the problems happened

MainActivity

```java
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);
        Contact Try2 = new Contact();       

        //Setting attributes of object
        Try2.setName("Try2");
        Try2.setPhoneNumber("01125532553");
        Try2.setId(0);
        //Adding contact
        databaseHandler.addContact(Try2);

        //Displaying contact in Log.d
        List<Contact> contactList = databaseHandler.getAllContacts(); //Error coming at this line
        for(Contact c:contactList)
        {
            Log.d("All_Contacts_Name","onCreate "+ c.getName());
            Log.d("All_Contacts_Number","Contact "+c.getPhoneNumber());
            Log.d("All_Contacts_Id","Contact "+c.getId());
        }

    }
```

getAllContact() program

```java
public List<Contact> getAllContacts()
    {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selectAll = "SELECT * FROM "+Util.TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectAll,null);

            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do{
                    Contact contact = new Contact(); 
                    
                    contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))); //Error coming at this line
                    contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                    contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));

                    contactList.add(contact);
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        return contactList;
    }
```

Edit:
This is my Util class

```java
public class Util {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="contact_db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact_table";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
}
```

This is the addContact function (used to add the contact)

```java
    public void addContact(Contact contact)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // "this" means we need to invoke it in *this* class.
                                                        // getWritableDatabase gives us one empty database to work.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); //Stores values for us (Secret tool we will use afterwards in line 65)
        //We will now be extracting values from contact
        values.put(Util.KEY_NAME,contact.getName());
        values.put(Util.KEY_PHONE_NUMBER,contact.getPhoneNumber());

        //Insert a row (it is essentially doing the same thing which onCreate was doing above, maybe).
        db.insert(Util.TABLE_NAME,null,values); //This will give db all the values required. Also, idk what nullColoumnHack is
        db.close(); //Remember kids, if you open dynamic memory then always close it. Not doing this results in memory leak.
        //Log.d("Added_Contacts","Contact Added");
    }
```

Comment: What type is the first column in the SQL SELECT? Can it be null? You should really avoid `SELECT *` in my opinion and instead list the columns you want returned.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am not sure what you meant by type for the first column but if you meant in reference to table then it was column id which was of type String `public static final String KEY_ID = "id";`

Comment: What type is it in the database table, that is what I meant.

Comment: I have column of int id, string name and string phoneNumber

Comment: Then if the column is an int why do you read it as a string to start with and not a number?

Comment: I did that but then Log.d was giving me random values to name. Like at this moment it is giving me 21 times getName. When I debug it so size of arrayList comes out as 21 right now.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone tell me what does this error means?

You've invoked `Integer.parseInt(x)`, where x evaluates to `null`.

And this occurred on the line so marked in that stack trace (so, line 132 of `DatabaseHandler.java`, because that is the code that calls parseInt. That parseInt then called another parseInt and that threw the error).

Generally to read a stack trace:

- First scan for 'caused by' lines, and skip everything until you get to the final cause. Well, skim over it, it does provide context. Thus, forget about the RuntimeException about 'unable to start activity'. The idea is: Some exception occurred, and because of that exception, the activity cannot be started. That's godo context, but the most important problem is whatever caused the activity to not be able to be started. Thus, we get to the NumberFormatException.
- Then, skip past any methods in classes you did not write. So, skip past java.lang.Number.parseInt until you get to your DatabaseHandler.java. That's the crucial line.

`cursor.getString(0)` resolved to `null`, which you passed to `Integer.parseInt`, which causes a null pointer exception. `null` means: "Unknown, Irrelevant, Not Applicable, Not Found". What's the integer variant of an unknown string? There is no way to tell, hence, exception. `null` does not mean '0' or 'blank' - if it does in your code, update that, and return an actual 0 or blank (i.e. if you ever write `if (x == null || x.isEmpty())`, that is strongly indicative you've messed up; once you treat `null` as semantically similar to some other value, such as in that case, treating it as an empty string, redesign a few things, that's not what null is supposed to be used for).

You can do two things:

- Most likely correct: Investigate why in the blazes one of your DB rows has a `null` for an `id` value. That doesn't sound right at all. If you want a magic value to indicate something special, consider reserving a special number for this, such as 0. While we're at it, why are there strings in your database that track numbers? Shouldn't there just be.. numbers in them? If there are, `cursor.getInt(0)` works just as well. Note that it's up to the implementation of the cursor as to what happens when you invoke `.getInt(0)`, when the value that is in the DB in the 0-index column is `null`. It can throw that NPE just the same.
- Instead deal with the fact that it is null. You can either invoke `cursor.isNull(0)` to check FIRST, or you can just get the string, not pass it to Integer.parseInt, check if it is null, and act accordingly. For example:

```
// instead of:
contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));

// do:
String rawId = cursor.getString(0);
if (rawId != null) contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(rawId));
```

But, as I said, it's far more likely you want to update your DB design not to have nulls in that column in the first place.

Comment: I have used `if(cursor!=null) cursor.moveToFirst();` in the above function and `db.insert(Util.TABLE_NAME,null,values);` (db is getWriteableDatabase. I don't know why null was used here, the tutorial used null so I copied it). Other than that, I have used null while selection arguments (given in code). I checked my other files too and there is no mention of null with id there (which I could comprehend). Should I post my other file's code too? I would be really helpful if someone could point out the error as I am trying since yesterday to catch the error.

Comment: Update - I have uploaded all the necessary info. It would be really kind of you if you can tell me the exact change I should be doing.

Comment: @ARYANSHARMA I think I spelled everything out in clear and excruciating detail. If you can't follow it, I regret that I do not have the chops to try to teach this to you; I simply do not know what more to say to make this any clearer. Perhaps try reading it a second time, and try to understand it all?

Comment: Yes sir you spelled everything crystal clear and I think I might know what the problem is (cant pinpoint the reason but a guess). As I was using parseInt but I assigned my id as TEXT in SQL so it might understand it as null. Thank you for your input. It really helped me in this :)